# Gradle call constructor on extension

Tags: gradle

I am writing a custom plugin for Gradle. I want to be able to have:

```
serviceDependencies {
    service name: 'service1', version: '1.0'
    service name: 'service2', version: '1.1'
}
```

In my Plugin implementation (in Java) I have:

```
public void apply(final Project project) {
    project.getExtensions().create("serviceDependencies", Services.class);
    project.getExtensions().create("service", Service.class);
}
```

And Service.java:

```
public class Service {
    private String name;
    private String version;

    public Service(final String name, final String version) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(final String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

When I try use this plugin I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find any public constructor for class com.xxx.xxx.Service_Decorated which accepts parameters [].
```

This still happens when I remove serviceDependencies/Services.java from the picture.

If I remove the Service constructor or remove the arguments.

```
org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method service() for arguments [{name=service1, version=1.0}] on root project ...
```

Obviously my pojo is being decorated, but not quite with the correct constructor. How can I get the constructor to work how I want in my build.gradle script?

A second and independent question is what should Services.java look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would only register one extension for `serviceDependencies {}` that exposes functions to register your services:

```java
public class Services {
  void service(String name, String version) { /* new Service(...) */ }
}

project.getExtensions().create("serviceDependencies", Services.class);
```

This would allow Java, Kotlin and Groovy consumer to do something like:

```
serviceDependencies {
  service 'service1', '1.0'
  service 'service2', '0.1'
}
```

Then if you want to support Groovy named arguments you'd need to add:

```java
public class Services {
  void service(String name, String version) { /* new Service(...) */ }

  void service(Map<String, String> namedArguments) {
    service(namedArguments.get("name"), namedArguments.get("version"))
  }
}
```

This would allow Groovy consumers to do:

```
serviceDependencies {
  service name: 'service1', version: '1.0'
  service name: 'service2', version: '0.1'
}
```